# Weird case with routes and error_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I have this error controller:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def error_404
    @not_found_path = params[:not_found]
    @return_page = request.referer || root_path
    errors_respond 404
  end

  def error_500
    errors_respond 500
  end
end
```

and in my `applicaiton_controller.rb` I have

```
def render_error(status, exception)
  errors_respond status
rescue
end
```

The render_error method is defined in the `application_helper.rb`-file

```
def errors_respond(status)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :template => "errors/error_#{status}", :layout => 'layouts/application_bootstrap', :status => status }
    format.all { render :nothing => true, :status => status }
  end
end
```

At the very bottom of my `routes.rb`-file I have

```
match '/i_really_do_not_exist', to: redirect('/') # WTF? error_controller_specs will fail if this is removed
match '*not_found', to: 'errors#error_404'
```

The mentioned `error_controller_spec.rb` is this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ErrorsController do
  describe "GET 'error_404'" do
    it "returns http status 404" do
      get 'error_404'
      response.response_code.should == 404
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'error_500'" do
    it "returns http status 500" do
      get 'error_500'
      response.response_code.should == 500
    end
  end
end
```

If I run them without the `'/i_really_do_not_exist'` path, they fail with

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:controller=>"errors", :action=>"error_404"}
```

The same is true if I removed the `/`.

I can change both the matching part and the redirecting part and my specs will pass, however they fail if I remove it entirely.

The route generated by the `match '/i_really_do_not_exist' => redirect('/')` is `:controller#:action`.

Anybody knows what's up?

Comment: Have you tried comparing ```rake routes``` outputs with vs. without those lines?

Comment: I edited the question to contain the route for `/i_really_do_not_exist`, which is `:controller#:action`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory.

You might not actually have a route to errors#error_404.  When rspec tries to access it, this line:

```
match '/i_really_do_not_exist' => redirect('/')
```

redirects it to the errors controller and action.  Without that line, a RoutingError occurs since there is no route.

Inspect the output of `rake routes` to see whether or not a route to errors#error_404 exists.  If not, check your routes file and your file names.  It's easy to incorrectly name a file `error_controller.rb` instead of `errors_controller.rb`.

Edit:

I think when you do

```
get 'error_404'
```

in `errors_controller_spec` RSpec tries to GET `/errors_controller/error_404`, which isn't in your routes.  Of course, you don't actually expect anyone to go to that URL so it's correct not to have it in your routes.
I think what you should do is have a spec to reflect expected behavior: that is to route to errors#error_404 when someone tries to access something that doesn't exist.  You might want to do this in a different spec file since it describes general behavior.  See:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

Comment: I do indeed have a routes to `error_404`. When running `rake routes` this comes out: `/*not_found(.:format)  errors#error_404`.

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen Yes but RSpec doesn't know about that.  See my edited answer.